# CDI conversation discontinues, when multipart/form-data is used

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

We use JSF 2.1, Glassfish 3.1.

We have a similar file upload solution to the one explained here: http://balusc.blogspot.hu/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html

The problem is that when the form is set to multipart/form-data, a new conversation is started on post, which breaks our app. Of course we could store information in SessionScoped beans instead, but we would like stick to ConversationScope if possible. We didn't try it with omnifaces ViewScoped.

Did anyone faced this issue? thx

Comment: As a quick test, try adding `?cid=#{conversation.id}` to the `<form action>` using JavaScript on page load. Btw, OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` won't help. The problem lies deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried BalusC's answer and it works fine. Attaching the 'cid' to the rendered form's action works. In fact, if there is an input field named 'cid', JSF can return to the conversation. This latter solution is simpler.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="#{conversation.id}" />
```

Thanks!